# Mouse sensitivity

Tags: mouse, gaming

So, I got a new mouse just 5 days ago. It's the X3ME 2 from MSI. It's a cool looking gaming mouse and it really fits into my hand nicely but the problem with it is that when I play fps games and lift the mouse it still moves in-game. The laser on it responds to movement 1 centimeter above my mousepad, I tried it without the mousepad too, it's the same result. It really makes my aim worse in the game. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into the settings for the mouse and change the **liftoff range**, I don't own the mouse myself so i don't know were that setting is exactly.

My guess would be thats in the settings with the software that MSI provides (you might have to download it). If you can't find it maybe send an email or call MSI to find out.

Comment: After realizing how big of an idiot I am, I found out that the mouse is actually MS. Do you know any software for MS mice?

Comment: Nevermind, I spent the last hour looking for that kind of software.. Nothing.. I'm just gonna use my old one and return this one to the store I got it in.

Comment: I've had a few MS mice before, the ones that i had plugged in and just worked but then also installed a piece of software (https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) that was used to change a few settings. It might work for you if you don't have it yet